# Get computer time c++

Tags: c++, time

I am using C++. I want to get computer time (I know how to do with ctime function). I want to take time like a int variable (sec, min, etc.). Any help?

Something like:
int sec = get.sec();
int min = get.min();

I don`t want a time_t variable.

Comment: It might be operating system specific.

Comment: It looks like you haven't done any research. // Closed as duplicate. The linked question has something that gives you seconds since the epoch.

Comment: Have you googled for `c++ time`? The first link was to (time)[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/] with references to the (`gmtime`)[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/gmtime/] function at the bottom. It looks like the `tm` struct has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) you could use [`<chrono>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/). You might also use [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html), [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html), [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html), [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html), [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) (if your system have them). Probably

```
 time_t now=0;
 time(&now);
 char nowbuf[64];
 strftime(nowbuf, sizeof(nowbuf), "%c", localtime(now));
```

might be relevant if you want some string. Otherwise, notice that `localtime` returns a pointer to a `struct tm` which has many numerical fields. e.g.

```
struct tm* lt = localtime(now);
int hours = lt->tm_hour;
int minutes = lt->tm_min;
```

Of course, in principle you should need to test against failure of `time`, `localtime` etc... (but I never had these functions fail).

Details are usually operating system specific. If on Linux, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html); some framework libraries like [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) might provide a common (OS independent) abstraction above them.

BTW, you may or not care about [time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) and you might want `gmtime` instead of `localtime`.

Comment: Well, yes, but I want something like this:
int sec = get.sec();
int min = get.min();

Comment: now, must be a struct :)

Comment: What must be a `struct`? `now` (passed to `time(&now)` ...) is defined as `time_t now=0;` and is a numerical type (an integral type on every system I know of).

Comment: int main()
{
    time_t timer;
    struct tm y2k;
    double seconds;

    y2k.tm_hour = 0;
    y2k.tm_min = 0;
    y2k.tm_year = 100;
    y2k.tm_mon = 0;
    y2k.tm_mday = 1;

    time(&timer);  /* get current time; same as: timer = time(NULL)  */

    seconds = difftime(timer,mktime(&y2k));

    printf ("%.f seconds since January 1, 2000 in the current timezone", seconds);

    return 0;
}